# Debugging app code during execution test on Appium

Tags: android, debugging, gradle, breakpoints, appium

I’m running functional test from Android Studio on Appium server and I want to debug my application code during the execution tests. I’m wondering if exists some way to use breakpoints and how can I do it.
In more detail, my functional tests are written in Java and I execute them through Gradle from Android Studio.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

How is that possible to debug app code using appium. 
Explanation: Appium always uses the compiled and executable zipped app code in form of .apk so that means when you start testing with appium your app code starts executing now appium doesn't have any control over source code, thats why I believe you can't debug the app code using appium.